# How to create a simple password form / script with redirection? (a tiny bit of security needed also)

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords

I'd like to create a simple password form or script that redirects the visitor to another page after the correct password has been entered.

The only security requirement is some sort of password scrambling / hashing (if the password is visible in source code).

The password ain't protecting anything valuable but it would be used in a web-based competition, and that's why it's important to minimize the obvious cheating options :)

I cannot code much myself (beyond HTML/CSS) so any help is greatly appreciated. I think this kind of script would be useful for other coding newbies also.

If you have any further questions, fire away!

Comment: Does it need to be a script? [Apache's authentication and authorization support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) is already written and debugged.

Comment: @sarnold, any working solution is ok. I've no idea how to use Apache auth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML form with method post and href to 'auth.php';

```
<form action="/auth.php" method="POST"><input type="text" name="password"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

source of auth.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['password'])) { 
    if(md5('blah@#$'.sha1('3NhNj8&'.$_POST['password']) ) =='MD5 value of your password' ) {
    header("Location: http://www.nextpage.com"); /* Redirect here if the password is correct */
    }
    else {
        header("Location: http://www.pagewheretheformis.com"); /* Return here if the password ain't correct */
    }   
}
else {
    header("Location: http://www.pagewheretheformis.com"); /* Return here if the field is empty */
}
?>
```

So you just need to run one time:

```
<?php echo md5('blah@#$'.sha1('3NhNj8&'."yourpassword")); ?>
```

and insert it into code above :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer pomaxa! How do I run that md5 thingy?

Comment: In case you're confused about the first line, something like: `<form action="auth.php" method="POST"><input type="text" name="password"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></form>` should work.

Comment: @Juuso, you can just put `echo md5('blah@#$'.sha1('3NhNj8&'."yourpassword")` in some .php file, replace "yourpassword" with your password (quoted), and load the file in your webbrowser.  It'll display some gibberish like t5av093sz -- copy that and then insert that into your auth.php where it says 'YOU NEED TO CHANGE IT'

Comment: @jedwards, ok now I get it. Thanks for the translation! I'll report back to you guys when I've tested it.

Comment: @jedwards, I created a .php file that had that "echo..." wrapped in <?php ... ?> tags but it doesn't show anything in a browser (tried FF and Chrome)

What I'm doing wrong now? :)

Comment: @juuso -- its not your browser so don't worry about that.  Both the answer and my comment missed the second closing parens.  Try: `<?php echo md5('blah@#$'.sha1('3NhNj8&'."yourpassword")); ?>`

Comment: @jedwards, still the same result unfortunately. Can you get it work on your computer?

Comment: My bad, the browser didn't work but it seems that the http://codepad.org/ can run it smoothly :)

Comment: I can (the output is: `32b61427cbbf26a8584a89b33f637e11` when the pw is "yourpassword") -- do any errors appear?  if you put an `echo "[";` before the md5 line and an `echo "]";` after, do you see the square brackets?  both?

Comment: So now I've got the md5 value placed in that .php file that @pomaxa posted, and the form placed and configured at a page. When I try to enter the password, it returns this error:

"HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: what action url do you type in html form?

Comment: if  there is  your auth.php file. And you can update your auth.php file, with little fixes i've made in this post. just to echo errrors.

Comment: What kind of CHMOD rights auth.php file needs? I gave it full rights (777) and now it doesn't print any errors, but the redirect doesn't seem to work. It returns 404 with correct and incorrect passwords.

Comment: Codepad gave this kind of error for the PHP-script (if it helps): "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line 3"

http://codepad.org/eZDcXJh0

Comment: if(md5('blah@#$'.sha1('3NhNj8&'.$_POST['password']) ) =='9091f8bb97d5520c45987eff9412b799' )

Comment: Now the code works, but the "Fill in your password" line returned error about unexpected T_ELSE. Thanks for your help guys :) I love StackOverflow!

Comment: @Juuso Palander, Since this code now works for you, please [mark this answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @BrockAdams, it works to this point but still misses one critical step. If the field is left empty the user goes to blank auth.php file and that's not desired action.

Comment: Could someone help me with the last issue?

Comment: you could try to put in the end of file something like : header("Location: http://yoursite.com");

Comment: Yeah solved it already, thanks! You, pomaxa, and the other contributors saved my day :)